# RMarkdown: Latex Table Output Difficulties

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

assume the following Markdown script:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Name"
date: "11/1/2015"
mainfont: "CMU Sans Serif"  
output:
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
  fig_caption: yes
  keep_tex: yes
---

# Estimation
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(ztable)
x = 1:10
y = x^2+1
model <- nls(y~x^c1, start=list(c1=1), control=list(maxiter=200))
z <- ztable(model, type="latex")
print(z)
```
````

If I knit this file to pdf, I get an latex error message like "Missing $ inserted". What causes this error is the fact, that the model formula uses `^` that are not escaped. If you check the ztable object `z`you'll notice that.

Now, how can I format the formula before or after creating the table object and replace `^`by `\^`? I can't find any "formula element" in `z`.

Hope I made my point clear. Taking logarithms is not taken as a solution ;)

Comment: That’s quite simply a bug/missing feature in `ztable`, you should report a bug there.

Comment: In fact, I’ve gone ahead and [submitted an issue](https://github.com/cardiomoon/ztable/issues/3). Since this looks like a very cool package.

Comment: Yes, it is cool indeed. And as far I know the only package supporting latex output of nls models. Thanks, hopefully they fix this fast ;)

Comment: Well, no reactions so far :/